# columns type error when using a custom sorter function on Ant Design table

Tags: typescript, antd

I'm trying to add a custom sorter function to a column in an Ant Design Table component. To do this, I've defined a `compareStringsByKey` function that takes a generic type `T` and a key of type `K` that corresponds to the object property to be sorted.

Here's the code:

```
const compareStringsByKey =
  <T, K extends keyof T>(key: K) =>
  (objA: T, objB: T): number => {
    if (typeof objA[key] === 'string' && typeof objB[key] === 'string') {
      const upperStrA = (objA[key] as string).toUpperCase();
      const upperStrB = (objB[key] as string).toUpperCase();

      return upperStrA.localeCompare(upperStrB, 'en', {
        numeric: true,
        sensitivity: 'base',
        caseFirst: 'lower',
      });
    }

    return 0;
  };
```

I'm using this function to define a custom sorter for a column in my table. However, when I try to compile this code, I get the following error message. Here's the relevant code:

```
// interfaces.ts
import { Table } from 'antd';

type EditableTableProps = Parameters<typeof Table>[0];
export type ColumnTypes = Exclude<EditableTableProps['columns'], undefined>;
```

```
import { ColumnTypes } from './interfaces';

export const columns: (ColumnTypes[number] & {
  editable?: boolean;
  dataIndex: string;
})[] = [
  {
    title: 'ID',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    key: 'id',
    width: '12rem',
    ellipsis: true,
    // "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'."
    sorter: compareStringsByKey('id'),
    editable: true,
  },
  //...
];
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to fix it. Can anyone help?

I wrote this code out from the this link
[Editable Cells](https://codesandbox.io/s/dyu9ru?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Are you missing the type to supply in angle brackets to your method - compoareStringsByKey?

Comment: guess you're right. but adding `compoareStringsByKey<object, string>` generated another error "Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'."

Comment: Can you provide the computed definition of `ColumnTypes` ? It seems like `ColumnTypes.sorter` is typed as `never`

Comment: do you mean this? `type ColumnTypes = (ColumnGroupType<object> | ColumnType<object>)[]`. I added the link you can see the definition file of Ant Design

Answer (score 0):

`compoareStringsByKey<InterfaceOfTableRow, keyof InterfaceOfTableRow>('id')` resolved the issue. Thank you guys!