# How to properly define antd editable table columns type

Tags: typescript, types, antd

I'm working on build an editable table using antd in typescript, following the guide [antd: table edit row](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-edit-row).

For now it works fine as an editable table, whether editing or displaying data.

However, since i'm using typescript, there're some errors with column type.

Here's my Item definition and column value.

```js
interface CleanFilterItemLabel {
    key: string;
    name: string;
    color?: string;
}

interface CleanFilterItem {
    id: React.Key,
    state: string,
    keyword: string,
    create_at: number,
    edit_at: number,

    author?: string,
    level?: number,
    group?: number,
    labels?: CleanFilterItemLabel[];
}

  const edit_tabel_column = [
    {
        title: t("editPage.level"),
        dataIndex: 'level',
        editable: true,
    },
    // {
    //     title: t("editPage.labels"),
    //     dataIndex: 'labels',
    //     editable: true,
    //     render: (labels: any) => (
    //       <>
    //         {labels.map((label: any) => {
    //           return (
    //             <Tag key={label.key}>
    //               {label.name}
    //             </Tag>
    //           )
    //         })}
    //       </>
    //     ),
    // },
    {
        title: t("editPage.group"),
        dataIndex: 'group',
        editable: true,
    },
    {
      title: t("editPage.state"),
      dataIndex: 'state',
      editable: true,
      filters: [
        {
          text: t("editPage.enabled"),
          value: 'open',
        },
        {
          text: t("editPage.disabled"),
          value: 'closed'
        }
      ],
      filterSearch: false,
      onFilter: (value: string, record: any) => record.state === value,
      render: (state: string) => (
        <>
          {state === 'open' ? <Badge status="error" text={t("editPage.disabled")}/> : <Badge status="success" text={t("editPage.enabled")}/>}
        </>
        ),
    },
    {
        title: t("editPage.keyword"),
        dataIndex: 'keyword',
        editable: true,
        ellipsis: {
            showTitle: false,
        },
        ...getColumnSearchProps('keyword'),
    },
    {
        title: t("editPage.createAt"),
        dataIndex: 'create_at',
        ellipsis: {
            showTitle: false,
        },
        editable: false,
        sorter: (a: any, b: any) => a.create_at - b.create_at,
        render: (create_at: number) => (
        <Tooltip title={time.get_date_string_from_timestamp(create_at, "YYYY-MM-DD")} placement='top'>
            {time.get_date_string_from_timestamp(create_at, "YYYY-MM-DD")}
        </Tooltip>
        ),
    },
    {
        title: t("editPage.editAt"),
        dataIndex: 'edit_at',
        ellipsis: {
            showTitle: false,
        },
        editable: false,
        sorter: (a: any, b: any) => a.edit_at - b.edit_at,
        render: (edit_at: number) => (
        <Tooltip title={time.get_date_string_from_timestamp(edit_at, "YYYY-MM-DD")}>
            {time.get_date_string_from_timestamp(edit_at, "YYYY-MM-DD")}
        </Tooltip>
        ),
    },
    {
        title: t("editPage.operation"),
        dataIndex: 'operation',
        render: (_: any, record: CleanFilterItem) => {
          const editable = isEditing(record);
          return editable ? (
            <span>
              <Typography.Link onClick={() => saveEditingRow(record.id)} style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
              {t('editPage.save')}
              </Typography.Link>
              <Popconfirm title={t("editPage.sureToCancel")} onConfirm={cancelEditTableRow}>
                <a>{t('editPage.cancel')}</a>
              </Popconfirm>
            </span>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Typography.Link disabled={editingKey !== ''} onClick={() => editTableRow(record)}>
                {t('editPage.edit')}
              </Typography.Link>
              <Divider type="vertical" />
              <Typography.Link disabled={editingKey !== ''} onClick={() => removeRow(record)}>
              {t('editPage.delete')}
              </Typography.Link>              
            </div>
          );
        },
    }
  ]

  const mergedEditColumns = edit_tabel_column.map((col) => {
    if (!col.editable) {
      return col;
    }
    return {
      ...col,
      onCell: (record: CleanFilterItem) => ({
        record,
        inputType: col.dataIndex,
        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
        title: col.title,
        editing: isEditing(record),
      }),
    };
  })

  <Form form={form} component={false}>
    <Table 
        components={{
          body: {
            cell: EditableCell
          }
        }}
        rowSelection={rowSelection} 
        columns={mergedEditColumns} // here comes types error
        className={style.customTable}
        dataSource={tableData} 
        pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}
        scroll={{ y: 360 }}
        rowKey={"id"}
    />
  </Form>
```

and it leads to the following errors

```bash
Type '({ title: string; dataIndex: string; editable: boolean; filters?: undefined; filterSearch?: undefined; onFilter?: undefined; render?: undefined; ellipsis?: undefined; sorter?: undefined; } | { title: string; ... 7 more ...; sorter?: undefined; } | ... 6 more ... | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type '(ColumnType<CleanFilterItem> | ColumnGroupType<CleanFilterItem>)[]'.
  Type '{ title: string; dataIndex: string; editable: boolean; filters?: undefined; filterSearch?: undefined; onFilter?: undefined; render?: undefined; ellipsis?: undefined; sorter?: undefined; } | { title: string; ... 7 more ...; sorter?: undefined; } | ... 6 more ... | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'ColumnType<CleanFilterItem> | ColumnGroupType<CleanFilterItem>'.
    Type '{ title: string; dataIndex: string; editable: boolean; filters: { text: string; value: string; }[]; filterSearch: boolean; onFilter: (value: string, record: any) => boolean; render: (state: string) => JSX.Element; ellipsis?: undefined; sorter?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ColumnType<CleanFilterItem> | ColumnGroupType<CleanFilterItem>'.
      Type '{ title: string; dataIndex: string; editable: boolean; filters: { text: string; value: string; }[]; filterSearch: boolean; onFilter: (value: string, record: any) => boolean; render: (state: string) => JSX.Element; ellipsis?: undefined; sorter?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ColumnType<CleanFilterItem>'.
        Types of property 'onFilter' are incompatible.
          Type '(value: string, record: any) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(value: string | number | boolean, record: CleanFilterItem) => boolean'.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
InternalTable.d.ts(14, 5): The expected type comes from property 'columns' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableProps<CleanFilterItem> & { children?: ReactNode; } & { ref?: Ref<HTMLDivElement> | undefined; }'
```

I've checked this question [columns type error when using a custom sorter function on Ant Design table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578292/columns-type-error-when-using-a-custom-sorter-function-on-ant-design-table) and try add the following definition to my column, but it still fails

```js
const edit_tabel_column: (ColumnsType<CleanFilterItem> & {editable?: boolean}[]) = []
```

I'm not good at such a complex type definiation, so how should i give it a proper definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the column `onFilter` type has a type definition
`value: string | number | boolean, record: Item`

If we define our own `onFilter` type with definition like
`value: number, record: Item`

It will throw errors, claim tha `value: number` is not compatiable with `value: string | number | boolean`.

The solution is to let them have the same type definition as `string | number | boolean`.

And here's my reproduction link [Once on editable table columns has onFilter property, typescript claims that mergedColumns is not assignable type with columns](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/44675)